# Logstash parse field issue

Tags: logstash

i have a log print as follows,

```
"message" => "....",
"host" => "10.10.12.13",
"@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2016-04-13T01:52:43.535Z",
 "DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance" => "22 days, 16:33:23.24",
"SNMP-MIB::OID_0" => "example::bgpPeerState",
"source_ip" => "10.10.12.13"
```

I want to parse the string that is based on the prefix "specific" and add a field for this and remove the original

`"SNMP-MIB::OID_0" => "example::bgpPeerState"`

it's should looks like as below ,

```
   "message" => "....",
 "host" => "10.10.12.13",
 "@version" => "1",
 "@timestamp" => "2016-04-13T01:52:43.535Z",
 "type" => "snmptrap",
 "DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance" => "22 days, 16:33:23.24",
 "example" => "bgpPeerState",
"source_ip" => "10.10.12.13"
```

my conf,

```
filter
 {
        if "example" in [SNMP-MIB::OID_0] {
               # I don't how to parse it and add a field  ???

              }
      else
      {
                 .......
       }

}
```

As always, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `kv` filter:

```
filter {
    if "example" in [SNMP-MIB::OID_0] {
        kv {
            source => "SNMP-MIB::OID_0"
            value_split => ":"
            trim => ":"
            remove_field => "SNMP-MIB::OID_0"
        }
    }
}
```

}